# MongoDB Error while running the project with pm2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pm2

I am trying to run my code using pm2 and I again and again get the below error. I have provided the complete credential details in mongouri which has the username password the cluster name and the table name, also I have whitelisted my ip and now I dont understand why is this error coming. Any help will be appreciated

```
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:44 +00:00:      name: 'MongoNetworkError',
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:44 +00:00:      [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} },
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:44 +00:00:   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:46 +00:00: { MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:46 +00:00:     at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/home/ubuntu/creatanium-wallet-blockchain/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server_selection.js:309:9)
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:46 +00:00:     at ontimeout (timers.js:466:11)
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:46 +00:00:     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:46 +00:00:     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:267:5)
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:46 +00:00:   name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:46 +00:00:   reason: 
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:46 +00:00:    { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0-5etkj.mongodb.net cluster0-5etkj.mongodb.net:27017
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:46 +00:00:     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:46 +00:00:      name: 'MongoNetworkError',
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:46 +00:00:      [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} },
3|USDT_CRE | 2020-01-07 06:46 +00:00:   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: make sure if you are using `"NODE_OPTIONS": "--use-openssl-ca"` flag, you also has corresponding certificate path with a valid certificate.

Comment: I have tried that @Ashish Modi

Comment: make sure you add `{"useNewParser": true, "useUnifiedTopology": true}` while creating mongo client

Comment: Already Done @AshishModi

Comment: Hello! Please share your mongo connection URI (without your password of course) so we can check what is going on!

Comment: Here is the mongo uri @MattiaRasulo mongodb://root:<password>cluster0-5etkj.mongodb.net:27017?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: That does not seem to exist per your error. Are you using cloud mongo or local instance?

Comment: i'm using mongo atlas and it is not connecting on ec2 terminal

Answer (score 0):

Your connection URI is wrong. If you are using Mongo Atlas it cannot end with `:27017`.

Please log into your admin panel and click "connect" and "connect your application":

http://prntscr.com/ql150h

Copy a fresh string and paste it instead of what you have now inside your app:

http://prntscr.com/ql15cp

If this does not handle contact their assistance, they will help you sort this out.